# XSLT selecting one of two nodes with same name on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

XML example

```
 <item> 
  <name>AW</name>
  <name>Car</name>
 </item>
```

XSLT Code

```
 <xsl:if test="item/name='AW'">
 <xsl:value-of select="item[name='AW']/[name='Car']"/>
 </xsl:if>
```

My problem is how to choose the value in the second attribute name if the value is not known

For example

```
 <item>
  <name>AW</name>
  <name>Unknown</name>
 </item>
 
 <item>
  <name>BW</name>
  <name>Unknown</name>
 </item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *attributes* in your XML. Both `item` and `name` are *elements*.

If you have multiple `item` elements, each containing 2 (or more) `name` elements, and you want to return the string-value of the 2nd `name` element from the `item` element where the 1st `name` element contains the string `"AW"`, you could use simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="item[name[1]='AW']/name[2]"/>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAc